# Why does <path to conda> deactivate not work?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have installed the latest anaconda `version: 4.7.12` on Ubuntu Server 18.

In the terminal, why does `conda deactivate` but `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda deactivate` does not?

This is the output of `which conda`:

```
(base) root@jenkinstest:~# which conda
/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

When I run `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda deactivate`, I expected the same behaviour has the `conda deactivate` command, so deactivating the current conda environment.

But if I run `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda deactivate`, I am getting the following error:

```
(py36) root@jenkinstest:~# /root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda deactivate

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda deactivate'.
To initialize your shell, run

$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Please note that I already used `conda init shell`, as suggested, and I have also restarted the shell session. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

When using bash (or ash, zsh, or dash) as your shell, `conda` is actually a *function*, not a command, and `which` will not show you its definition.

The `conda` cli (command-line interface) is only meant to support setting up the shell integration, which is why you see the `conda init` error message.

If instead of `which conda` you run `type conda`, you'll see it's definition. Or look at the [`etc/profile.d/conda.sh` definition on GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.sh). `conda deactivate` runs `__conda_activate deactivate`, etc. Other shell integrations work along the same lines.

Conda uses shell specific integrations, so if you are not on bash one of these should apply:

- csh or tcsh: [`etc/profile.d/conda.csh`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.csh)
- fish: [`etc/fisd/conf.d/conda.fish`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish)
- xonsh: [`conda.xsh`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/conda.xsh)
- powershell: [`condabin/Conda.psm1`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1) (imported as a module via [`condabin/conda-hook.ps1`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1))
- cmd.exe: [`condabin/conda_hook.bat`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/condabin/conda_hook.bat) and from there [`condabin/conda.bat`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/condabin/conda.bat) and [`condabin/_conda_activate.bat`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/condabin/_conda_activate.bat).

*Under the hood* this does then use your `conda` cli, but with current shell information added in. These commands are hidden for a reason; they rely on the shell integration to ensure that the right shell commands are issued and evaluated *in your current shell*. You can't do this from a new process, as a child process can't otherwise alter your shell environment and set things like the `PATH` or add or remove other shell variables.

So `conda deactivate` in bash instead uses a bash function call, and when that function call then executes `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix deactivate` it does so as part of an [`eval` instruction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash). The `.../conda shell.posix deactivate` command outputs a series of bash commands, which `eval` then executes in your current shell and so deactivates the conda enviroment configuration.

So if you *really, really* wanted to use that command-line tool, you'd have to evaluate it's output yourself:

```sh
eval `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix deactivate`
```

The above is of course *specific to bash (compatible) shells!* The `` ` `` backticks around `/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix deactivate` tell bash to take the output of the command as a string to give that to `eval`. If you run it without the `` eval `...` `` part, you'll see the commands it issues:

```sh
(base) root@jenkinstest:~# /root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix deactivate
export PATH='/root/newinstall/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
unset CONDA_PREFIX
unset CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
unset CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
export CONDA_SHLVL='0'
export CONDA_EXE='/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/conda'
export _CE_M=''
export _CE_CONDA=''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='/root/newinstall/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

(note that that only produces output in an *active conda environment*).